# how to fire progressbar events jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

if i use this scripts and css files

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>progressbar</title> 
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi');
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 70 });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="progressbar"> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is working fine.
but here i am using the other css files as because i am working for the mobiles.
 my project contains this is styles and scripts

```
    <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi');
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 70 });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressbar"> 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using ***jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css*** for styles and ***jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js*** for jquery.
so i have observed the styles in previous css file as

```
 .ui-widget {
 font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
 font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
  }
 .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/; background:        #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/; color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/; }
 .ui-progressbar { height:2em; text-align: left; }
 .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {margin: -1px; height:100%; }
```

these styles are using for progress bar . so i copied them to ***jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css***

but some calls are made in ***jquery-ui.min.js*** to apply the progressbar styles.

so how could accomplish this task without adding those files.

any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through with the below example. You can call these function on any of the event. This is just to populate the Progress Bar on the Mobile Platform and you can customize it as per the need.
Also you have to add 2 JS and a CSS to populate the progress bar.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

You can import the JS and CSS file given on the link above and then you can use the below code on Android WebApp.

```
    $(function() {

        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
        setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);

        });

        function updateProgress() {
          var progress;
          progress = $("#progressbar")
            .progressbar("option","value");
          if (progress < 100) {
              $("#progressbar")
                .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 5);
              setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);
          }
        }
```

This will move the progress with the increment of five after delay of half second. You can modify it as per the need.

Hope this will help you

Kind Regards,

Summved